# Match two consecutive words in a sentence

Tags: python

I have a bunch of sentences and want to figure out if the sentence contains a specific set of consecutive words. As an example, I have a list like below

```
  list = ["Data Scientist",  "Data Analyst", "Data Engineer"]
```

and have sentences like below

```
  Sentence1 = "I am first going to be a Data Analyst and then a Data Scientist"
  Sentence2 = "I only like to be a Data Engineer"
```

with the desired output picking out "Data Analyst" and "Data Scientist" for Sentence1 and "Data Engineer" for Sentence2.

Comment: Can't you just use index()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Yatu's example data. Use regex which will be definitely faster than `in` operator

```
import re

l = ["Data Scientist",  "Data Analyst", "Data Engineer"]
Sentence1 = "I am first going to be a Data Analyst and then a Data Scientist"

re.findall("|".join(l),Sentence1)
```

Output:

```
['Data Analyst', 'Data Scientist']
```

Comment: You beat me to it by 5s! Nice.

Comment: Your regex is simpler than mine. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list comprehension and the [`in`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details) operator to check membership:

```
l = ["Data Scientist",  "Data Analyst", "Data Engineer"]
Sentence1 = "I am first going to be a Data Analyst and then a Data Scientist"

[i for i in l if i in Sentence1]
# ['Data Scientist', 'Data Analyst']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regex for that:

```
import re

lst = ["Data Scientist",  "Data Analyst", "Data Engineer"]

s = re.compile('|'.join(lst))

matches = re.findall(s, senetence)
```